# Maui Android CredentialManager context problem

Tags: android, .net, maui, androidx, maui-blazor

I am trying to create a [.NET MAUI Wrapper](https://github.com/Kebechet/Maui.CredentialManagers) around `AndroidX.credentials` and I am trying to use it in my Maui Blazor app.

When I want to call [_credentialManager.CreateCredentialAsync](https://github.com/Kebechet/Maui.CredentialManagers/blob/main/src/Maui.CredentialManagers/Platforms/Android/Services/CredentialManagerAndroidService.cs#L134-#L140) like:

```
_credentialManager.CreateCredentialAsync(
    act,
    request,
    null,
    ContextCompat.GetMainExecutor(act),
    callback
);
```

I get an error

> "Failed to launch the selector UI. Hint: ensure the `context`
> parameter is an Activity-based context."

I have tried several different ways how to obtain the context:

```
var context1 = Platform.AppContext;//1
var context2 = Platform.CurrentActivity.BaseContext;//2
var context3 = Platform.CurrentActivity?.ApplicationContext;//1
var context4 = Application.Current?.Handler?.MauiContext?.Context;//1
```

but none of them work. Is there a different way how to obtain the correct context ? Or is there a different problem ?

---

PS: This call works on my `Pixel6(api34)`, but doesnt work on my simulator with `Pixel4(api33)` nor on my `SamsungS9(api29)`. Based on [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/credentials/CredentialManager#createCredential(android.content.Context,androidx.credentials.CreateCredentialRequest)) this method should be available.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? .NET7 or .NET8

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT `v8.0.101`

Comment: You can try the code: `Android.Content.Context context = Platform.CurrentActivity;
_credentialManager.CreateCredentialAsync(
    context,    request,
    null,
    ContextCompat.GetMainExecutor(act),
    callback
);`

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT omg, yes this worked, thanks. Please create an answer ideally with a short explanation why Activity can be used instead of context and I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you encountered with the `_credentialManager.CreateCredentialAsync()` method stems from the necessity of providing a context parameter that is based on an Activity.

In Maui, to obtain the current Activity instance, you can use the following code:

```
  Android.Content.Context context = Platform.CurrentActivity;
```

This method returns the current running Activity, allowing you to pass it as a context parameter to relevant APIs.